# Script being triggered too soon

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace my sliders default "1, 2, 3" navigation with words using Jquery.

I have it working with this code:

```
//CHANGES SLIDER NUMBERS TO TEXT FOR NAVIGATION
$(".rslides_tabs .rslides1_s1 a").text("Automotive");
$(".rslides_tabs .rslides1_s2 a").text("Residential");
$(".rslides_tabs .rslides1_s3 a").text("Sign & Millwork");

//WRAPS SLIDER NAV IN CONTAINING DIV FOR CSS PURPOSES
$("ul.rslides_tabs").wrap("<div class='rslides_wrap'></div>");
```

My problem is, half the time when I load the page it works and half the time it doesn't. I feel like it's getting called too soon sometimes or something. I have tried wrapping it in both a Window.Onload, and Document.Ready (and both of those combined), but it still randomly doesn't work sometimes on page load. I've also tried the code above the < head > tag, and right before the < /body > tag, but that doesn't make a difference.

Any suggestions on what I can do to make it work 100% of the time?

http://tcgi.com.lindsayviscount.com/

Comment: Show an example when you're trying document ready, just to make sure that you're doing that one right, since that should work.

Comment: It's kind of obnoxious for us to look through your entire webpage. You should just break it down to the relevant HTML. Also, it seems this is the script code `$(window).load(function() {$( document ).ready(function() {//OP's code});});`

Comment: JoeEnos $( document ).ready(function() { }); is what I was wrapping it in. And that doesn't work at all. Only Window.load seems to work. @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc It's kind of hard to break down a wordpress site that's using a plugin for a slider, otherwise I would have made a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what browser you are using but after taking a look at the source code I did notice the following:

- JS is building the initial 1,2,3
- The Automotive, Residential, and Sign & Millwork has a dedicated `.ready(){}` block
- You are using jQuery 1.11.2 and 1.10.2 an not resolving the conflict
- **You've placed the metaslider into a `setTimeout()` block**

Some suggestions for code cleanup:

- Definitely remove the `$(window).load(function() {`
- Stick to one version of jQuery

**TL;DR;**

The likely cause of your issue is the fact that `setTimeout()` creates a separate thread so 1,2,3 is not available to be targeted when the code for Automotive, Residential, and Sign & Millwork has been called.

Comment: The metaslider is a plugin, so I have no control over what that is loading. I'm using firefox 1. I changed my version of Jquery I was loading to 1.11.2 to try and match the other one 2. I removed the window.load function but then it stops working altogether. document.ready by itself also does not seem to work.

Comment: @KerynGill Have you checked the plugin's documentation to see if it will allow you to set the tab values upon initialization? The `setTimeout()` initializes the slider after 100 milliseconds. Ignoring everything I said besides `setTimeout()`, in theory you could offset the code for Automotive, Residential, and Sign & Millwork by 150-200 ms and then it *should* reliably work. It will be quite a crude band-aid fix, though.

Comment: the timeout does work, but you're right it's quite crude. Maybe I will look into trying to shove the words in with CSS instead. I just thought Jquery would be easier. However adding in a '1' delay seems to make it work all the time and you can barely notice the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

you could put the code in a function and edit your html to this:

```
<body onload="yourFunction()">
```

sorry if this isn't what you wanted, cuz i didnt quiet understand what you said